# Having trouble getting $_GET variables in Wordpress shortcodes

Tags: php, wordpress

Calling $_GET['ip'] worked up until a recent wordpress update and now it's broken.

I don't know how Wordpress expects me to get the variable but the code I've been messing with and put together doesn't seem to work at all.
I'm clearly doing something wrong but I can't seem to wrap my head around making this work.

The code I'm trying to work with is here: https://pastebin.com/4iipisjU

**UPDATE:** The code works, the WPSupercache configuration file for nginx is what seems to have broken it.

Comment: how is it "not working" can you show an example of how the like url is showing up on the page?

Comment: the variable `$_GET['ip']` is literally empty inside of the function. https://www.dnsbl.im/lookup?ip=1.2.3.4 (it only gets the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`get_query_var`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

```
<?php

    $value = get_query_var( "paramA", "default value" );
?>
```

Also, `$_GET['ip']` will refer to the query parameter IP that was passed as part of the request.

Is this actually what you are looking for? Or are you trying to see the IP of the client making the request? If the latter, this is incorrect.

Comment: I'm trying to get $_GET['ip'] but it seems to be empty, in the code I posted you will see that I have already tried `get_query_var` and it doesn't work either.

Comment: You have not posted any code. If you want me to read it, add it to the body of the question. For this to work, your request IS in fact passing a parameter named 'ip', correct?

Comment: Yes, the url is https://www.dnsbl.im/lookup?ip=1.2.3.4 for example. The code is the pastebin link in the original post ( https://pastebin.com/4iipisjU )

Answer (score 0):

Try change `$get_ip_addr` to:

```
$get_ip_addr = get_query_var('ip', $_GET['ip']);
```

Comment: Did it, and it's unfortunately still not working. the second parameter (where I had `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) according to the Wordpress documentation is supposed to be for default value if the first is not provided.